# Magento Customer Login Notification Email Sent to Customer

Tags: email, magento, templates

Is there an easy solution for the customer to receive a notification email every time login to the store?

i am creating extension

app/etc/Module **Custom_Notify.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Notify>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Notify>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/Notify/etc **config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Notify>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Notify>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <events>
    <customer_login>
        <observers>
            <cnotify>
                <type>model</type>
                <class>cnotify/observer</class>
                <method>customerNotify</method>
            </cnotify>
        </observers>
    </customer_login>
    </events>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <cnotify>
        <class>Custom_Notify_Helper</class>
      </cnotify>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <cnotify>
        <class>Custom_Notify_Block</class>
      </cnotify>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <cnotify>
        <class>Custom_Notify_Model</class>
      </cnotify>
    </models>  
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/Notify/Model/**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Custom_Notify_Model_Observer {

  public function customerNotify($observer) {

    /* for  Template  */
    $template_id= '1';

     $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    $recepient = array(
        'name' => $customer->getName(),
        'email' => $customer->getEmail()
    );


    $sender = array(
        'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'),
        'email' => Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')
    );

    $email_template_variables = array(
        'customer_name' => $customer->getName(),
        'customer_email' =>  $customer->getEmail()

    );

    $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    $email_template->setSenderName($sender['name']);
    $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender['email']);
    $email_template->send($recepient['email'], $recepient['name'], $email_template_variables,$storeId);


    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any issue in code or error you facing?

Comment: Path to observer should be `app/code/local/Custom/Notify/Model/Observer.php`. You're missing `Model`, unless it's just a typo in the post.

Comment: To answer your question, the code you've provided is pretty much the easiest solution to accomplish this task.

Comment: i did not get any error and also not result

Comment: @cyk   actually i could not post app/code/local/Custom/Notify/Model/Observer but i have post in my directory